# viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() always returns -1

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

For some reason I'm not able to use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` because it always returns -1 but `holder.getLayoutPosition()` returns a position just fine.

My onCreateViewHolder:

@Override

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                     int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false);


    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(this, v);
    return vh;
}
```

My ViewHolder constructor:

```
public ViewHolder(DirectoryListAdapter adapter, View linear) {
            super(linear);
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.linear = (LinearLayout) linear;
            this.entryName = (TextView) linear.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            this.entryImage = (ImageView) linear.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

}
```

I looked a bit further and `getAdapterPosition` looks like this:

```
 public final int getAdapterPosition() {
            final ViewParent parent = itemView.getParent();
            if (!(parent instanceof RecyclerView)) {
                return -1;
            }
            final RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) parent;
            return rv.getAdapterPositionFor(this);
        }
```

And basically what is happening is that the ViewParent is null. Any idea why that might be?

Other than that my recycler is working just fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be an issue on the new version of the support library (22.1.0).

Answer (score 1):

If parent is null, that means ViewHolder is not a child of RecyclerView thus we have not been tracking its position. Layout position is its latest position when it was laid out.

In the following releases, we'll extend the scope of getAdapterPosition.

Comment: So am I doing something wrong? should I be setting the parent?